# How to get Selenium Webdriver to recognize elements with changing id numbers within it

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, element

how do I get the xpath or css or ANYthing to click this ok button??? Problem is these ids and other attributes have tags that are changed every time a user goes to this particular page
--ea3b2e21-3847-47de-860c-3596695fbb35-- so i don't know what to do

Ok

Comment: Can you post the html or at least a snippet?

Comment: Your post has no helpful details as to what you are trying to accomplish. Please update your question with relevant information, like a link to the page you are referring to, some HTML snippets of which element(s) you are trying to access, and some code that you have already written. Plenty of users are available here to help you if you give us detailed information about your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do here is try and find some part of the element that does not change. If you can add some sample html it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the
[docs for dynamic elements?](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#locating-dynamic-elements)